# how to break line to next line depending on device width in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel

I am newbie to ios and i am learning tableView with custom cells,I have make a code for that successfully,but now i have a problem that a label in which i am setting title text is cutting right side to device width,i want that text to come in next line if it is cutting with device width.can anybody please tell?

My code is as below
 **code**

```
  UILabel *titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];

   CGRect frame = self.titleLbl.frame;
    frame.size.height = [self getHeightforController:self.titleLbl];
    self.titleLbl.frame = frame;


    titleLbl.text = str;
```

here durationtxt is a quite long string and its cutting right side.

Comment: please check my answer below i wrote.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @irfan-yes.I am using autolayout for my uiTableView,it dispalying perfect in iPhone6,but Slightly cut on right side in iphone5.

Comment: If you are using autolayout then you don't need to calculate frame for label. Just bound your label with cell. And it will grow according to textSize.

Comment: @irfan-but its not happening..!! as per you are telling,I have taken an autolayout in my uiTableView but still have no luck in iPhone5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function where you need dynamic height for all devices it will work

```
- (CGFloat)getHeightforController:(id)view{
UILabel *tempView =(UILabel *)view;
NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;

float width = tempView.frame.size.width;

width = width * ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/320);

CGSize size=[tempView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tempView.frame.size.width, 200)
                                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                     attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : tempView.font}
                                        context:context].size;
return size.height;
}
```

it will return you required height for your label and call this method like :

```
CGRect frame = self.yourlbl.frame;
frame.size.height = [self getHeightforController:self.yourlbl];
self.yourlbl.frame = frame;
```

That solved..

Comment: I have tried your solution it says `Property titleLbl not found on Objectof type "ViewController"`

Comment: hello please see my edit,in that your suggested code show me error as in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The UIKit Framework Reference is going to be your best friend. Here is a link to the [UILabel Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/index.html).

You will need to set the `durationLbl.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap` and also set the `durationLbl.numberOfLines` if needed. 0 means any number of lines and is the default.

Answer (score 0):

update you code  :`UILabel *titleLbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];                        titleLble.text = str
   CGRect frame = titleLbl.frame;
frame.size.height = [self getHeightforController:titleLbl];              titleLbl.frame = frame;'`

you are getting this error because titleLbl is object of your cell not your ViewController. and please dont forget to set text before calling that method

Comment: I have changed as per your code,but no change in UI.Still it goes single line and cut by device width.!!!

Comment: go in xib and open attribute inspector for label and give no. of lines 0

Comment: or add in code after setting text.  titleLbl.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @shubham-no chnage..!!! changed it both the ways,i mean it works for only some of lables in tableView.weired results..

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but can you please share your code whatever you wrote in cellforRowAtIndexpath

Comment: because have used this method in 10 to 12 project . i never faced issue

Answer (score 0):

please once try this :

```
lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
lbl.text = str;
[sizeToFit];
```

without calling that method